# Is it possible to retrieve data of all classes in Parse using single REST URL request?

Tags: parse-platform

just a scenario :
I have 4 classes created in Parse cloud database for a particular Application - ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD.
I can retrieve data related to ClassA using REST URL like - https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClassA
Is it possible to retrieve data of all 4 classes using single REST URL ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do this.  You can query from a single class at a time, and a maximum of 1,000 objects.

A cloud function can make multiple queries and merge the results, meaning that a single REST call (to call the function) could return results from multiple classes (but a maximum of 1,000 objects per query).   Something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("GetSomeData", function(request, response) {

  var query1 = new Parse.Query("ClassA");
  var query2 = new Parse.Query("ClassB");
  query1.limit(1000);
  query2.limit(1000);

  var output = {};

  query1.find().then(function(results) {
    output['ClassA'] = results;
    return query2.find();        
  }).then(function(results) {
    output['ClassB'] = results;
    response.success(output);
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
  });
});
```